# Fix N Crash (i cant Fix it or it will crash) Loop and Break in java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement, break

I have tried to fix this and each time I fix this it becomes broken. what I'm trying to do is create a calculator and has the basic operations and asks you if you wan another equation solved again if necessary. it will even asks you to type in the operation if you typed it in wrong.

the code is this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Thread;

public class Calculator

    int B1;
int C1;
int D1; // error here
@SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(;;)
            System.out.println("How May i asist you with your calculation."); {
            System.out.println("So what opperation do you want to use. ");
            Scanner A1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String in = A1.nextLine();
                if (in.equals("+")){
                    System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                    Scanner Z = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int B1 = Z.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                    Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int C1 = Y.nextInt();
                    int D1 = B1 + C1;
                    System.out.println(" you answer is " + D1 + ".");}
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Again?");
                    Scanner A = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String B = A.nextLine();
                        if (B.equals("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Ok");
                        if (B.equals("No"))
                            System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                            break;}
                else if (in.equals("-")){
                    System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                    Scanner Z = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int B1 = Z.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                    Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int C1 = Y.nextInt();
                    int D1 = B1 - C1;
                    System.out.println(" you answer is " + D1 + ".");}
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Again?");
                    Scanner C = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String D = C.nextLine();
                        if (C.equals("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Ok");}
                        if (C.equals("No"))
                            System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                            break;{
                if (in.equals("*")){
                    System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                    Scanner Z = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int B1 = Z.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                    Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int C1 = Y.nextInt();
                    int D1 = B1 * C1;
                    System.out.println(" you answer is " + D1 + ".");}
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Again?");
                    Scanner E = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String F = E.nextLine();
                        if (E.equals("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Ok");}
                        if (E.equals("No"))
                            System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                            break;{
                if (in.equals("/")){
                    System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                    Scanner Z = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int B1 = Z.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                    Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int C1 = Y.nextInt();
                    int D1 = B1 / C1;
                    System.out.println("You answer is " + D1 + ".");}
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Again?");
                    Scanner G = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String H = G.nextLine();
                        if (G.equals("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Ok");}
                        if (G.equals("No"))
                            System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                            break;{
                    if (!in.equals("+"+"-"+"*"+"/"))
                        System.out.print("That's Not a valid operation.");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Again?");
                        Scanner I = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String J = I.nextLine();
                            if (I.equals("Yes")){
                                System.out.println("Ok");}
                            if (I.equals("No"))
                                System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later"); 
                                break; { //error here
```

I don't know where else the errors are but it needs to be fixed pronto.
please help me
I didn't eat my lunch
I didn't get to have a break a school
and I spent 2 hours at home trying to fix this.
but I cant.
please help me

Comment: What does _it's broken_ mean?

Comment: I don't see a single closing bracket in your code.  Rule of thumb - for every opening bracket `{` there needs to be a matching closing bracket `}`

Comment: @SamDufel There are some there... it's poorly indented.

Comment: Ah, they're hidden!  It's still missing several, though

Comment: Why `break; {`? Specifically, what block are you trying to open (and why)?

Comment: this is not an appropriate question for stack overflow.  see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your brackets.  Make sure when you're creating a loop that you wrap the contents of the loop in curly brackets `{}`.  When you're writing a condition, make sure you wrap each section in curly brackets.

Here's the first half of the corrected program, I'll leave to you to write the rest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Thread;

public class Calculator {   // missing opening bracket

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int B1;
        int C1;
        int D1;     

        for(;;) { // missing opening bracket
            System.out.println("How May i asist you with your calculation."); // removed extra opening bracket here
            System.out.println("So what opperation do you want to use. ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    // you only need one scanner
            String in = scanner.nextLine();
            String response;

            if (in.equals("+")){
                System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                B1 = scanner.nextInt();     // only declare variables once
                System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                C1 = scanner.nextInt();
                D1 = B1 + C1;
                System.out.println(" you answer is " + D1 + ".");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Again?");

                scanner.nextLine();  // clear out the previous newline
                response = scanner.nextLine();
                if (response.equals("Yes")) {
                    System.out.println("Ok");
                }
                if (response.equals("No")) {   // wrapped in brackets
                    System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (in.equals("-")){
                System.out.println("Enter the first Number. ");
                B1 = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter The last Number. ");
                C1 = scanner.nextInt();
                D1 = B1 - C1;
                System.out.println(" you answer is " + D1 + "."); 
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Again?");

                scanner.nextLine();  // clear out the previous newline
                response = scanner.nextLine();
                if (response.equals("Yes")){
                    System.out.println("Ok");
                }
                if (response.equals("No")) {
                    System.out.println("Ok. ill see you later");
                    break;
                }

            }   // changed opening bracket to closing bracket

        }
    }
}
```